# How to use one UIPickerView for two textfields in one view?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have 2 textfields in one view. I want to populate each using a pickerview. Currently I have succesfully made one picker with one textfield working perfectly but once I edited the code to make it working with two textfield it does not working as expected. Any help will be much appreciated.

Below is my code :

```
#import "TestPickerVC.h"

@interface TestPickerVC () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *aktivitiArray;
    NSArray *penganjurArray;
}

@end

@implementation TestPickerVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.penganjurTextField.delegate = self;
    self.aktivitiTextField.delegate = self;

    aktivitiArray = @[@"apple", @"samsung", @"motorola", @"nokia"];
    penganjurArray = @[@"jimbit", @"ayam", @"kambing", @"emergency"];


//    self.aktivitiTextField.inputView = self.pickerView1;
//    self.penganjurTextField.inputView = self.pickerView2;

    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;


    self.aktivitiTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;

    self.penganjurTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;

    self.aktivitiTextField.tag = 1;
    self.penganjurTextField.tag = 2;



//    if (self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 100) {
//        self.aktivitiTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;
//        self.pickerView.tag = 1;
//        NSLog(@"pickerview tag : %d", (int)self.pickerView.tag);
//    } else if (self.penganjurTextField.tag == 200) {
//        self.penganjurTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;
//        self.pickerView2.tag = 2;
//        NSLog(@"pickerview tag : %d", (int)self.pickerView2.tag);
//
//    }

}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 1) {

        return aktivitiArray.count;

    } else if (self.penganjurTextField.tag == 2) {

        return penganjurArray.count;
    }

    return 1;

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 1) {
        return aktivitiArray[row];
    } else if (self.penganjurTextField.tag == 2) {
        return penganjurArray[row];
    }

    return @"";
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView Delegate

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *selectedAktivitiRow = aktivitiArray[row];
    NSString *selectedPenganjurRow = penganjurArray[row];


    if (self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 1) {
        self.aktivitiTextField.text = selectedAktivitiRow;
    } else if (self.penganjurTextField.tag == 2) {
        self.penganjurTextField.text = selectedPenganjurRow;
    }

}




-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

Comment: I don't get it you want one pickerView for two textFields or 2 pickerView for 2 textfields?

Comment: @kholl one pickerView for two textFields

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. What is the exact issue you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another private variable as selectedTextField.

```
@interface TestPickerVC () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *aktivitiArray;
    NSArray *penganjurArray;
    int selectedTextField
}
```

The moment you tap on text field, textfield delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` will be called. In this method, do -

```
selectedTextField = textField.tag;
```

Now in picker delegate methods, check with this condition :

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (selectedTextField == 1) {

        return aktivitiArray.count;

    } else if (selectedTextField == 2) {

        return penganjurArray.count;
    }

    return 1;

}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (selectedTextField == 1) {
        return aktivitiArray[row];
    } else if (selectedTextField == 2) {
        return penganjurArray[row];
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Do likewise for all picker delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really explain what your issue is but looking at the code there is a pretty glaring issue. Let's look at one method as an example:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 1) {
        return aktivitiArray.count;
    } else if (self.penganjurTextField.tag == 2) {
        return penganjurArray.count;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The problem here is that the first `if` statement will always be true. Regardless of which text field the picker is for, `self.aktivitiTextField.tag == 1` is always true. You have this issue in all of the picker view methods.

You need to check which text field is currently being used. Try the following pattern in all of the picker view methods:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if ([self.aktivitiTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        return aktivitiArray.count;
    } else if ([self.penganjurTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        return penganjurArray.count;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use .editing for textfields and returns the respective arrays.
Ex:

```
if (aktivitiTextField.editing) {

        return aktivitiArray.count;

    } else if (penganjurArray.editing) {

        return penganjurArray.count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3 this is worked for me. Below is the code.

```
//MARK:- picker view methods


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if (textFieldName .isEqual(to: "firstDoseFld")) {
        return arrFirstDose.count

    }
    else
    {
        return arrFrequency.count
    }



}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (textFieldName .isEqual(to: "firstDoseFld")) {
        return arrFirstDose[row]
    } else  {
        return arrFrequency[row]
    }




}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (textFieldName .isEqual(to: "firstDoseFld"))
    {
        selectedFirstDose = NSString()
        selectedFirstDose = arrFirstDose[row] as NSString!
        let cell : AddMedicationCell = ordersTable.cellForRow(at: indexPathForCell as IndexPath) as! AddMedicationCell

        cell.firstDoseFld.text = selectedFirstDose as String?

    } else
    {
        selectedFrequency = NSString()
        selectedFrequency = arrFrequency[row] as NSString!
        let cell : AddMedicationCell = ordersTable.cellForRow(at: indexPathForCell as IndexPath) as! AddMedicationCell

        cell.frequencyField.text = selectedFrequency as String?

    }


}
```

In textfield delegate method do like this

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{



    print("textfield is ..\(textField)")

    if textField.placeholder == "First Dose"
    {
        textFieldName = "firstDoseFld"
    }
    else if textField.placeholder == "Frequency"
    {
        textFieldName = "frequencyFld"
    }

    activeTextfield = textField

    print(selectedTextField)
    return true;
}
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath do like this(set delegate of custom cell textfield) and adding toolbar also here

```
orderCell.firstDoseFld.delegate = self
    orderCell.frequencyField.delegate = self

let toolBar4 = UIToolbar()
        toolBar4.barStyle = .default
        toolBar4.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar4.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar4.sizeToFit()
        let doneButtonForFirstDoseFld = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(AddMedicationOrderVC.doneClickedForFirstDoseFld))
        let spaceButton4 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        // let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "cancelClick")
        toolBar4.setItems([spaceButton4, doneButtonForFirstDoseFld], animated: false)
        toolBar4.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        orderCell.firstDoseFld.inputView = pickerView
        orderCell.firstDoseFld.inputAccessoryView = toolBar4
        orderCell.firstDoseFld.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Let me know if you need more information. Delare variables based on requirement for this.